# How to provide username and password for composer install?

Tags: php, bash, vagrant, composer-php

I am installing a `composer` project with:

`php composer.phar install`

Part way through it prompts for my GitHub username and password for access due to API hits. How can input my username and password when I run the command from a bash script? The bash script is a vagrant provisioner.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of a way to specify github credentials to composer via the command line but you can set them up [prior to running the install command](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#api-rate-limit-and-oauth-tokens):

1. [Create an OAuth token on GitHub.](https://github.com/settings/applications)
2. Add it to the configuration running `composer config -g github-oauth.github.com <oauthtoken>`

Alternatively you can modify the [config files manually](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#config). You can create an auth.json file that has the needed credentials (I didn't verify this syntax...):

```
{"github-oauth": {"github.com": "oauthtoken"}}
```